# Adding a new row, transferring information, and adding a timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, charts, timestamp

The system I'm making is for archiving purposes. The program I found allows for me to transfer the information I have in a specific cell (from the logging interface) to the correct sheet, and it makes another row for the archive table.

However, the problem is that I also need the program to insert a timestamp within the archive sheet.

The column only exists within the archive sheet-- transferring the current time from one sheet to another seems like it's own separate problem.

Here's the program I have:

```vb
Sub Transfer()

    Dim config, itm, arr
    Dim rw As Range, listCols As ListColumns
    Dim shtForm As Worksheet
    

    Set shtForm = Worksheets("Interface") '<< data source

    With Sheets("Archives").ListObjects("table_work")
        Set rw = .ListRows.Add.Range 'add a new row and get its Range
        Set listCols = .ListColumns  'get the columns collection
    End With

    'array of strings with pairs of "[colname]<>[range address]"
    config = Array("Unit<>A2", "Machine<>B2", "PC<>C2", "Software<>D2", "Who<>E2", "Why<>F2")  

    'loop over each item in the config array and transfer the value to the
    '  appropriate column
    For Each itm In config
        arr = Split(itm, "<>") ' split to colname and cell address
        rw.Cells(listCols(arr(0)).Index).Value = shtForm.Range(arr(1)).Value
    Next itm

End Sub
```

Here's what I came up with:

```vb
Sub Timestamp()

Dim timecol
Dim rw As Range, listCols As ListColumns
Dim shtForm As Worksheet

With Sheets("Archives").ListObjects("table_work")
        Set listCols = .ListColumns 

timecol = Array("When<>G2")
```

That's about as far as I get before drawing a blank. I just need for the program to also add a timestamp to the newly made row. I'm so clueless about how any of this works, but I would like to make it function if I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you first add a column for the timestamp to the existing Table (for this code to work, must be the last row on the right of the Table) in the "Archives" sheet then add a line just before the `End Sub` line of your `Transfer` Sub:

```
rw.Parent.Cells(rw.Row, rw.Column + rw.Cells.Count - 1).Value = Now
```

If you want, you can change the formatting of what is added for example

```
rw.Parent.Cells(rw.Row, rw.Column + rw.Cells.Count - 1).Value = Date & ", " & Time
```

Comment: A shorter version, I believe with the same result: `rw.Cells(1, rw.Cells.Count) = Now`, or `rw.Cells(1, 7) = Now`